# Do we need both [watchkit] and [apple-watch]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I noticed that we have two tags for Apple's next device, [apple-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) and [watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit). Do we need both? Anything that someone on this site (a developer) is going to be doing with an Apple Watch is through WatchKit, so I don't see what value having two tags adds.

I propose that we synonymize [apple-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) to [watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit). Am I missing something?

Comment: Upvoted. Apple-watch can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think WatchKit is better....