# Make [iwatch] a synonym of [apple-watch]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I believe [iwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iwatch) is a nickname for [apple-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) (Apple calls it [Apple Watch](https://www.apple.com/watch/)), so the former should be a synonym of the latter.

Also, [all existing questions for the [iwatch] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iwatch?sort=newest) are related to either [Apple Watch](https://www.apple.com/watch/) or [WatchKit](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/).

*Related: [Do we need both [watchkit] and [apple-watch]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277182/do-we-need-both-watchkit-and-apple-watch)*

Comment: isn't iwatch a trade mark of a Chinese company that competes with the Apple Watch?

Comment: Yeah. I don't recall if the company is chinese, but "iWatch" definitely does not belong to Apple.

Comment: @Chenmunka Can you find any examples of questions tagged with [tag:iwatch] which refer to a product of that Chinese company, instead of to Apple Watch? It doesn't matter who *technically* holds the trademark on that name, it's pretty clear that in terms of controling usage of that term [they've already lost big-time](https://www.google.com/search?q=iwatch).

Comment: @acdcjunior according to [this article](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmacilove.com%2Fnews%2Fapple-has-applied-for-trademark-registration-in-russia-iwatch%2F&edit-text=&act=url) Apple had started trademark registration process for name iWatch in Russia. So, this could be counter-argument. But, in this case I think one tag is better.

Comment: The point isn't that there are iwatch tagged questions about Apple Watch yet but that iwatch and Apple Watch are not the same thing.  Apple may obtain the iwatch trademark in various jurisdictions.  The difference will then go away.

Comment: @flinth Yes, and [there are a lot more](http://www.cnet.com/news/apple-extends-iwatch-trademark-filings-to-more-countries/) like that, it seems. But it is a fact that in European Union the trademark already belongs to a company called [Probendi](http://www.probendi.ie/iwatch.html), so iWatch in europe is not, technically, Apple Watch. Well, at least for now - nothing stops Probendi to sell "iWatch" to Apple. Anyway, I think this discussion goes beyond that. It'd be something more like "should we call a penguin a synonym of duck if everyone thinks a penguin is a duck"? Or something like that.

Comment: If people are frequently using the terms synonymously, *even if it's technically incorrect*, that says to me they should be made synonyms. If a new non-Apple product called "iWatch" springs up with an SDK, we can always deactivate the synonym later…

Comment: A moderator would probably have to do this, unless you want to hunt down the few users qualified to suggest tag synonyms on that tag (users with an answer score of +5 on that tag)